# Is there a way to stack JaggedArrays without fromiter()?

Tags: awkward-array

I have two 2D JaggedArrays of the same length (in axis=0) that I'd like to stack in axis=1. For example:

```
a = awkward.fromiter([[0], [3, 4]])
b = awkward.fromiter([[1, 2], [5]])
```

and I want to get this JaggedArray:

```
[ [ [0],    [1, 2] ],
  [ [3, 4], [5]    ]  ]
```

I can get exactly this with the following:

```
awkward.fromiter(np.stack([a, b], axis=1))
```

but is there a way to accomplish this directly in `awkward`, without having to use `fromiter()` on nested numpy arrays?